# Starting an opensplice publisher via systemd does not publish data

Tags: systemd, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I have an opensplice publisher on Ubuntu 20.04 that is started via systemd.

If the publisher starts via systemd then the data is not pubished, but also no errors are reported or present in the opensplice log files.

The publisher works if I run it from a command line or if I stop and restart the service.

The QoS are the same for the publisher and subscriber.

The publisher and subscriber applications are running on different machines.

There are no other participants on the network. All the machines are rebooted and the order of reboot does not change the observed behaviour.

The systemd service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Publisher Process
Documentation=
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/publisher/bin
ExecStart=/opt/publisher/bin/publisher.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `publisher.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/publisher/bin
source bashrc_local
# We just keep running the application (in case of a crash)
while true; do
  ./publisher
  sleep 15
done
```

I have a work around that feels a little bit naff.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/publisher/bin
source bashrc_local
timeout 30 ./remote_processor
killall remote_processor
# We just keep running the application (in case of a crash)
while true; do
  ./publisher
  sleep 15
done
```

Any ideas on how I can remove my work around?

## Edit 16 Sept 22

The issue appears to be systemd start order and dependencies as I have run into the same issue with a program publishing data via UDP which is not using DDS.

Changing the dependencies so the services are started just before the user login does not help.

Answer (score 0):

check your environment variables as systemd will not run with the same environment as your bash console

in particular have you set the OSPL_URI variable to point at the config?

if using the commercial version, OSPL_HOME and ADLINK_LICENSE will also need to be set

Does the PATH variable include your OSPL shared libraries?

These are all setup by running the $OSPL_HOME\release.com script in your bash session

I tend to manually add the required ones to the service file
e.g.
Environment=OSPL_URI=file:///opt/ospl.xml

Comment: The `source bashrc_local` sets up the environment correctly. The work around is to kill the publisher in the shell run via systemd and to rerun the publisher inside that shell straight afterwards. The implication is that the issue is something else given that the second run of the application works without hanging.